# Задержка выполнения скрипта в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет. Реализовываем рассылку почту. Есть БД подписчиков, есть Шаблон рассылки. Что мы делаем, выбираем шаблон и нажимаем отправить рассылку. Рассылка уходит по всей БД. Но есть одно НО. хостинг ругается и говорит что в час можно слать 500 писем. И тут возник вопрос, как сделать задержку, т.е. отправили 500 писем, задержка в час, отправили еще 500 писем, задержка час и тд. Поможет ли функция sleep. Я запускаю цикл, перебираю БД, шлю письма и как только счетчик достикает 500 я вызываю функцию sleep (3600); Потом продолжаю выполнения скрипта.
Сработает или совсем костыль?

Comment: Здесь уместно использовать планировщик задач cron.

Comment: Если у вас очень много записей в БД,то это повесит сервер. Хост будет недоволен. Лучше бы повесить выполнение скрипта на cron. Только входные данные будут меняться (с какой записи начинать рассылку)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да хост просто отрубит скрипт. Там обычно стандартно на shared хостингах max_execution_time стоит 60 секунд

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Как уже советовали, только крон и маркер по БД отправлен - это если для shared-а.
2. Не рекомендую делать рассылку собственными силами со своего IP, так как легко попасть в black list и потом важные письма доходить не будут. Пользуйтесь специальными сервисами рассылок — есть много бесплатных на начальной стадии. Если переживаете за конфидинциальность — нужно свой почтовый сервер подымать - но опять же рекомендую на отдельном IP.

Comment: Спасибо! Повешу тогда на Cron